# VS Code Code Navigation inside haml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, haml

I have been playing around with VS Code hoping to switch over from the pricier Jet Brains option. However "you get what you pay for" may hold true here.

I have a rails project that uses haml templates and I have some inline javascript in these haml files. Like so:

```
- content_for :head do
  :javascript
    $(document).ready(function () {
      initializeCurrencyFormattingOnAllCurrencyElements();
      if (typeof table_manager === 'undefined') {
        table_manager = new DatatableManager();
      }
      var sales = new AsyncDatatable('sales', '#sales', 100, {}, false, true, 1);
      sales.handle_form_submit();
      table_manager.add(sales);
      table_manager.init_all();
      table_manager.draw_all();
    });
```

In the JetBrains IDE it was no problem ctrl/command hovering over these javascript definitions inside the haml file and I could use code navigation to go straight to the definition of things like "AsyncDatatable", "handle_form_submit()", etc. However I cannot get this to work in VS Code. I struggled for a while to get code navigation working for ruby as well (my installation came with a blank settings.json file for some reason) So I don't know whether I just don't have the right extensions, settings, or whether this just is asking too much from a free IDE.

Has anyone succeeded in doing this either with haml or erb? Any tips would be greatly appreciated even if the answer is that this isn't currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i have been using VScode for a while and what i do is copy the phrase i want to find e.g. "AsyncDatatable" and then using search (shift+command+F for mac) that shows that phrase even if it appears multiple times inside your code.